# Use the second countability of $\mathbb{R}^k$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $A$ be a collection of open subsets in $R^k$, Euclidean space. Then there is a subset of $ A_0$ of $A$ such that $A_0$ is either countable or finite and $\bigcup A_0=\bigcup A$.

I don't know enough about second countability to approach this question.

Comment: I don't think the question has been copied correctly from its source. Please double-check the exact wording.

Comment: @ChrisCulter this is the exact wording thanks for asking. Why do you say it's wrong?

Comment: The first sentence, "Let $A$ be a collection of open subsets in metric space", isn't grammatically correct. Maybe it's supposed to be "Let $A$ be a collection of open subsets in **a** metric space." But if that's the claim, then it's false. For a counterexample, let $A$ be the discrete partition of an uncountable set with the discrete metric. And what does this have to do with $\mathbb R^k$?

Comment: @ChrisCulter Then there is a problem with the original statement, I have edited my question to mean what I think makes most sense. Thanks for explaining.

Comment: Ah, okay! I would start by expanding the statement that $\mathbb R^k$ is second countable into its definition, and expanding that definition until you can relate it to $A$.